# Bash from scratch

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I know this may sound ridiculous, but in my defence I'll say I'm at the very beginning of messing around with coding and bash in particular, so don't judge me too harshly...

I just dipped into this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a number: "
read VAR

if [[ $VAR -gt 10 ]]
then
  echo "The variable is greater than 10."
fi
```

Thing is any number I write up doesn't change a thing. Even `2` will be greater than `10`. What's wrong?

Comment: This scrpt works fine for me: `Enter a number: 12
The variable is greater than 10.` What's exactly the problem ?

Comment: Please do `ls /bin/bash -l` and tell us what the output is. `/bin/bash --version` would also help.

Comment: You have two bad practices there: i) avoid using CAPS for variables. By convention, global environment variables are in CAPS and if you set yours that way too that can cause surprising bugs. ii) Always quote your variables when using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively (since you mention that you are learning bash) you could use an arithmetic expression:

```
if (( VAR > 10 ))
then
    echo "The value is greater than 10."
fi
```

Or the more concise one-liner:

```
(( VAR <= 10 )) || echo "The value is greater than 10."
```

Answer (score 5):

The script has a correct syntax, and works for me. If I enter anything from 0-10, it does not echo any text.

For future reference, I recommend you install [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make a habit of checking your script syntax with it.